# removeItem and changeQuantity methods not working

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, methods

i have a class named ItemToPurchase with private variable declarations and public methods to set and get the value of those variables. this class also has a defualt construtor and a constuctor that takes String's itemName and itemDescription as parameters.
example:

```
public class ItemToPurchase{
private String itemName;
public void setName(String name){
   ...
 }

public String getName(){
  return name;
 }
}
```

and then another class named shopping cart which does the same thing and it also contains this method.

```
private ArrayList<ItemToPurchase> cartItems;
cartItems = new ArrayList<ItemToPurchase>();           

public void removeItem(String itemName) {
    if (cartItems.contains(itemName)) {
        cartItems.remove(itemName);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Item not found in cart. Nothing removed.");
    }
}
```

and the class ShoppingCartManager contains the main and in the main there is a loop which prints a menu which looks like this.

```
ShoppingCart cart = new ShoppingCart(cName, tDate);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    ShoppingCart object = new ShoppingCart();
    System.out.println("Enter Customer's Name: ");
    String cName = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Today's Date: ");
    String tDate = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Customer Name: " + cName + "\n" + "Today's Date: "
            + tDate);

    ShoppingCart cart = new ShoppingCart(cName, tDate);
    printMenu(cart);
}
public static void printMenu(ShoppingCart cart) {
    char input;
    do {
        System.out.println("Menu");
        System.out.println("a - Add item to cart");
        System.out.println("d - Remove item from cart");            
        System.out.println("q - Quit");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Choose an option: ");
        input = sc.next().charAt(0);
        switch (input) {
        case 'a':
            addItem(cart);
            break;
        case 'd':               
            removeItem(cart);
            break;

        default:
        }
    } while (input != 'q');
}
public static void removeItem(ShoppingCart cart) {
    System.out.println("REMOVE ITEM FROM CART");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("Enter name of item to remove: ");
    String itemName = sc.next().trim();
    ShoppingCart object = new ShoppingCart();
    object.removeItem(itemName);
}
public static void changeItem(ShoppingCart cart) {
    System.out.println("CHANGE ITEM QUANTITY");
    System.out.print("Enter the item name: ");
    System.out.println("");
    String itemName = sc.next().trim();     
    System.out.println("Enter the new quantity: ");
    int nQuantity = sc.nextInt();
    ItemToPurchase oItemName = new ItemToPurchase();
    if (itemName.equals(oItemName.getName())){
    oItemName.setQuantity(nQuantity);   

    }
```

can anyone explain why the removeItem() and changeItem() methods aren't working?
let me know if you need to know more about the code.

Comment: `ArrayList contains` method and remove method need object of type `ItemToPurchase` and not String.

Comment: how do you know its not working ? (pun intended)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void removeItem(ShoppingCart cart) {
    System.out.println("REMOVE ITEM FROM CART");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("Enter name of item to remove: ");
    String itemName = sc.next().trim();
    ShoppingCart object = new ShoppingCart();
    object.removeItem(itemName);
```

}

---

the parameter **cart** you did not use, and so did your **changeItem(ShoppingCart cart)** method. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `removeItem` method looks for a `String` in a list of `ItemToPurchase`. The contains method calls `equals` on the String and in every object in cartItems looking for a match. Of course it will not find it.

Change your method to something like this:

```
public void removeItem(String itemName) {

    for (int i = 0; i < cartItems.size(); i++) {
        if (cartItems.get(i).equals(itemName)) {
            cartItems.remove(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```